# Convert varchar to date - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column of `date` values that are currently of type `varchar`. Could someone please explain the easiest way to convert these to actual dates. Below is a list of example values in the aforementioned column

```
 - Expiration Date 
 - 00/00/00
 - 11/06/10  
 - 00/00/00  
 - 29/02/08  
 - 01/04/11
```

NOTE: 00/00/00 means there is no expiration date, but they still need to be included somehow as I store other data on them.

Comment: What have you tried and why didn't it work? If you haven't tried, look up `TRY_CONVERT` and the [Date and Time Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles), and then post your attempt(s) if you fail.

Comment: Why you're storing `DATE`s as `VARCHAR(n)` in the first place? There is data types for reason. Use them wisely

Comment: What does `.../10` mean? 2010? 1910?

Comment: 1: I will try that thank you!

Comment: 2: Afraid I wasn't the one who created the table, i'm just trying to do some analysis using it but thanks for the comment

Comment: 3: Sorry, 2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data appears to be in dd/mm/yy format, so use `convert()` with format code 3:

```
select try_convert(date, str, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select case yourVarcharValue when '00/00/00' then NULL else Try_Convert(Date, yourVarcharValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case, need to select from converted results:

```
declare @myTable table(ExpirationDate  varchar(max)) 

insert into @myTable (ExpirationDate ) values ('00/00/00')
insert into @myTable (ExpirationDate) values ('11/06/10')
insert into @myTable (ExpirationDate) values ('29/02/08')
insert into @myTable (ExpirationDate) values ('01/04/11')

 select ExpirationDate from
 (
    select ISNULL(try_convert(date, ExpirationDate, 3), '9999-12-31') as ExpirationDate 
    from @myTable) d
 order by d.ExpirationDate asc
```

Results:

```
ExpirationDate
2008-02-29
2010-06-11
2011-04-01
9999-12-31
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to not store Date fields as NVARCHAR/VARCHAR:

```
select ISNULL(try_convert(date, ExpirationDate, 3), '9999-12-31') from myTable
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b5d04/2)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table myTable (ExpirationDate  varchar(max))
insert into myTable (ExpirationDate ) values ('00/00/00')
insert into myTable (ExpirationDate) values ('11/06/10')
insert into myTable (ExpirationDate) values ('29/02/08')
insert into myTable (ExpirationDate) values ('01/04/11')
```

**Query 1**:

```
select ISNULL(try_convert(date, ExpirationDate, 3), '9999-12-31') from myTable
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b5d04/2/0)**:

```
|            |
|------------|
| 9999-12-31 |
| 2010-06-11 |
| 2008-02-29 |
| 2011-04-01 |
```